# Import error - AppRegistryNotReady

Tags: python, django

I keep getting same error when I try to import User from django.contrib.auth.models, or any other model class from django.
I installed Python 3.7, made new virtualenv and this is full traceback of the error:

```
(trytest) C:\Users\User\Desktop\trytest\Scripts\trytest>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit 
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Marin\Desktop\trytest\lib\site- 
    packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, 
    BaseUserManager
File "C:\Users\Marin\Desktop\trytest\lib\site- 
    packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\Marin\Desktop\trytest\lib\site- 
    packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "C:\Users\Marin\Desktop\trytest\lib\site- 
    packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
File "C:\Users\Marin\Desktop\trytest\lib\site- 
    packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

This is just test project i installed to see if I will have same problem with clean installation. Virtualenv is active.
Is the problem with Python, or Django, I can't find anything useful online.

Comment: Did you run the Django shell? You are typically *not* supposed to import this in the Python shell, since it first needs to load the project and apps.

Comment: i'm embarrased.. I didn't work with Django for quite some time and I completely forgot that I have to run Django, not Python shell..  Thank you very much for quick answer

Comment: You can always run `import django` then `django.setup()` before importing stuff but running `manage.py shell` does this bootstrapping for you.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule between `import django` and `django.setup()` need to export `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Or `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")`

Comment: Very correct @JonhyBeebop I suppose running the Django shell is easier

Comment: great info, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to import User from Django.contrib.auth.models
I used get_user_model function from importing django.contrib.auth import get_user_model.

following is you should take to fix you error.
Check that Django is installed correctly: Make sure that Django is installed and up-to-date. You can check the Django version by running django-admin --version or python -m django --version.

Check that all dependencies are installed: Make sure that all of the required dependencies are installed and up-to-date. You can check the list of dependencies in the requirements.txt file in your Django project.

Check the Python environment: Make sure that you are using the correct Python environment and that all dependencies are installed in that environment. You can check the Python environment by running python --version and pip freeze.

Try reinstalling Django: If none of the above steps work, try uninstalling and reinstalling Django by running pip uninstall django and pip install django.

Try a different version of Django: If the issue persists, try using a different version of Django. You can install a specific version of Django by running pip install dj